# Write .each data to two different classes with same div id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery `.each` that loops through div id's and writes JSON data from an AJAX call to inputs assigned a class.
Most div's only have one row of inputs to populate, but some have two rows of input classes.
All divs and classes are created dynamically, but each dynamic div does get its own unique ID.

When the `.each` hits the div with two rows with the same class it does not write to both rows but writes to the second row of classes with the second row from the database.
When users write to the db with the data from both rows it creates a separate row in the db.
One for badge1, and one for badge2.
Here is my `.each` that writes one row of inputs great

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    $("#" + item.full_op_id).find('.badge1').val(item.badge1);
    $("#" + item.full_op_id).find('.badge2').val(item.badge2);
    $("#" + item.full_op_id).find('.op_date').val(item.op_date);
    $("#" + item.full_op_id).find('.op_qty').val(item.op_qty);
});
```

I have tried several things including an if/else statement on just those id's with two rows of classes.
I understand that when the `.each` sees the two rows it basically sees it as one row since they have the same class names except for badge1/badge2.

*Should I run another loop inside the `.each` to loop through and write both rows for that div id and same input classes? If so, how should I do this?*

Background on app:  Created with Foundation 5, dynamically creates each panel row with data from one DB (MSSQL), then using AJAX/JSON users write to a separate DB (MYSQL) their input data.
The user should then be able to pull up the job again and see what they have done by pulling their data from the MYSQL db of their inputs.
That is the db I am pulling the data from when trying to insert the JSON data to the inputs for each div row and inputs.

Here is the HTML that creates these two rows:

```
<div class="row" id="op_div_id">
  <div class="large-3 columns badge_div">
    <label>
      Operator 1 <span class="badge_required" style="font-size: 0.7em;">*required</span>
      <div class="row collapse">
        <div class="small-3 columns">
          <button class="button prefix radius badge_scan_button" onclick="badgeButton1($(this));">
          Scan
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="small-9 columns">
          <input type="text" class="badge1" name="badge1" onchange="badgeColor1($(this));" placeholder="Badge Number">
          <input type="hidden" class="time_assigned" name="time_assigned" value="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="large-3 columns date_div">
    <label>Today's Date <span class="date_required" style="font-size: 0.7em;">*required</span>
    <input type="text" class="op_date" name="op_date" onclick="popDate($(this));" placeholder="Today's Date">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="large-3 columns qty_div">
    <label>Quantity <span class="qty_required" style="font-size: 0.7em;">*required</span>
    <input type="text" class="op_qty" name="op_qty" onblur="opQtyColor($(this));" placeholder="Quantity">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="large-3 columns">
    <label>Complete Operation</label>
    <button class="button postfix save_op1" onclick="saveOp1($(this));">
    Save
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="op_div_id2">
  <div class="large-3 columns badge_div">
    <label>
      Operator 2 <span class="badge_required" style="font-size: 0.7em;">*required</span>
      <div class="row collapse">
        <div class="small-3 columns">
          <button class="button prefix radius badge_scan_button" onclick="badgeButton2($(this));">
          Scan
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="small-9 columns">
          <input type="text" class="badge2" name="badge2" onchange="badgeColor2($(this));" placeholder="Badge Number">
          <input type="hidden" class="time_assigned" name="time_assigned" value="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="large-3 columns date_div">
    <label>Today's Date <span class="date_required" style="font-size: 0.7em;">*required</span>
    <input type="text" class="op_date" name="op_date" onclick="popDate($(this));" placeholder="Today's Date">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="large-3 columns qty_div">
    <label>Quantity <span class="qty_required" style="font-size: 0.7em;">*required</span>
    <input type="text" class="op_qty" name="op_qty" onblur="opQtyColor($(this));" placeholder="Quantity">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="large-3 columns">
    <label>Complete Operation</label>
    <button class="button postfix save_op2" onclick="saveOp2($(this));">
    Save
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hey can you make a jsfiddle and give example of the If statement you had tried? a second loop should not be needed. looks like youre very close.  Its kind of confusion..

Comment: As an aside, significantly more efficient to select an ID once with the jQuery selector and reuse it rather than "#" + item.full_op_id four times when the result will be the same. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/pP8Zy/1/

Comment: ... or simply chain the methods: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/pP8Zy/2

Comment: Thanks @Jason your suggestion was helpful and I incorporated your response into my answer below.  Thanks everyone else for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for your support and help on this.  I have come up with a solution that works pretty well.  Thank you @Jason for the tip to only select the ID once.

```
         success: function (data) {

         var el;
         var done_row1 = false;
         $.each(data, function (i, item) {

             el = $("#" + item.full_op_id);

             if (item.full_op_id == "210-SUTB015" || item.full_op_id == "210-PICKA" || item.full_op_id == "44-SUTB015") {

                 if (done_row1 === false) {
                    el.find('div#op_div_id input.badge1').val(item.badge1);
                    el.find('div#op_div_id input.op_date').val(item.op_date);
                    el.find('div#op_div_id input.op_qty').val(item.op_qty);

                     done_row1 = true;

                 } else {

                    el.find('div#op_div_id2 input.badge2').val(item.badge2);
                    el.find('div#op_div_id2 input.op_date').val(item.op_date);
                    el.find('div#op_div_id2 input.op_qty').val(item.op_qty);
                     // reset row1 test
                     done_row1 = false;
                 }

             } else {
                el.find('div#op_div_id input.badge1').val(item.badge1);
                el.find('div#op_div_id input.op_date').val(item.op_date);
                el.find('div#op_div_id input.op_qty').val(item.op_qty);
             }

         });

     }
```

Another developer at my work helped me with this solution, so I am not 100% sure what it is doing to make it work but it is.  We just separated out the writing of the rows between badge1 and badge2 using another if/else statement and true/false statements. Thanks again everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand correctly, but try changing

```
$("#" + item.full_op_id).find('.badge1').val(item.badge1);
```

to

```
$("#" + item.full_op_id).find('.badge1').each(function() {
    $(this).val(item.badge1);
});
```